# WIFI Config isn't Working on ESP8266

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

Hi i have tried to set a fixed ip for esp8266 Lolin. But always when i power off the board and power on,  the IP changes.
What i'm doing wrong?

My code :

```
    WiFi.persistent(false); 
WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);                 
WiFi.begin(ssid, password); 
IPAddress ip(192,168,1,200); 
IPAddress gateway(192,168,0,1);
IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);
WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet);


while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
delay(250);
Serial.print(".");
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about an electronics module, not programming, and should be asked on the electronics stackexchange.

Comment: He's "programming", isn't he?  I think it's a legitimate question, and I believe other Arduino developers might experience exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is here:

```
https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/2371

You must set "WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);" after WiFi.config and before WiFi.begin
```